# Check username in database against logged in username MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller

I am fairly new to MVC3 and I am trying to create an order screen, where users can login and look at their recent orders. This is proving a problem as I am trying to pull username values from the database and compare them to the current logged in user, so that each user can only view their own orders and no-one elses. However I am struggling to convert the values from the database as strings in order to compare them to the logged in username.

Here is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Assignment2.Models
{
    public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId                      { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Username                  { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string FirstName                 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string LastName                  { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "House Number/Name")]
        [StringLength(70)]
        public string House                  { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Street Name is required")]
        [StringLength(70)]
        public string Address1                  { get; set; }

        public string Address2                  { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string City                      { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "County is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string County                    { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post Code is required")]
        [DisplayName("PostCode")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Postcode                  { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Country                   { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
        [StringLength(24)]
        public string Phone                     { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
        ErrorMessage = "Email is is not valid.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email                     { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public decimal Total                    { get; set; }


        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is what I'm trying to do with my controller

```
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Assignment2.Models;

namespace Assignment2.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private RevolutionEntities db = new RevolutionEntities();

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            string loggedinuser = User.Identity.Name;
            string username =   
                            from a in db.Orders
                            where a.Username == loggedinuser
                            select a;                            
            return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: What does your user object look like?  What are the attributes and data type for User.Identity.Name?

Answer (score 0):

```
var orders = db.Orders.Orders(p=>p.UserName == loggedinuser);
```